# Html5 elements not rendering. Html5shiv.js not applying to pages

Tags: html, validation, rendering, syntax-error

Im finishing my website and am now in the validation and browser testing stage.

So, my whole website has been converted to html5, as the default theme wasn't. After adding the conditional ie 9 comment to apply the html5shiv.js to browser versions below ie 9, some of the pages render properly and some do not.

Please view this page in Internet Explorer 8 (or ie9 but in version ie 8 from developer mode) to see the broken html5 page: http://www.gizmotrims.com/site/gizmotrims/music-ipods/1-ipod-nano.html

I troubleshooted this issue and wasn't able to find what is actually causing the pages to not render correctly and appear broken. Please note that not all of the pages have this problem, only a few. Its weird because some pages are fine and some aren't.

Could someone help me find this problem so I can finish the development of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to `js/html5shiv.js` does not seem to work. You could change it to `../js/html5shiv.js`, but that will probably ruin it for other pages. In this case you are better off using the absolute path (`http://www.gizmotrims.com/site/gizmotrims/js/html5shiv.js`) or a path relative to the root (`/site/gizmotrims/js/html5shiv.js`). You could also set a `base[href]`, but that would affect other references as well.